# Is undelete of comments already deleted.. possible?

Tags: discussion, comment, deletion, undeletion

If something new or relevant needs to be said, deleted comments if retraceable could be re-edited for renewed comments. Not needed often though.

Answer (score 19):

Moderators can undeleted comments that were not deleted by the users. Namely, if you posted a comment and you deleted it, then moderators cannot undelete it. If, on the other hands, a moderator deleted the comment, then they can be undeleted by moderators.

The problem is that you don't have access to deleted comments, so you can't quite edit them, or restore them easily. Of course this is moot, since users can only edit comments for the first five minutes after posting them.

(Of course, any SE administrator with access to the database can undelete comments.)

Comment: Maybe worth adding: mods can still see the self-deleted comments. So they could recover the content if needed.

Comment: It's also worth adding that this applies to anyone with sufficiently high reputation, since people are sometimes confused about what "moderator" means in the context of the SE network. I am a regular user who can see deleted posts (unsure if I can delete ones that are not self-deleted, since I don't see those often)

Comment: @StellaBiderman: We are talking about deleted *comments* - which only moderators can see (and work with, up to a certain limit, as explained above).

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!