# Why were the constructive comments deleted along with one poor comment?

Tags: discussion, comment, flagging, specific-flag

I flagged as unconstructive a spam comment to my answer of [mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6661/laplace-transformations-for-dummies/219688#219688).

I see that all the comments were deleted --- one of which was heavily upvoted and contributed greatly to the answer.

Is there anything that can be done to bring that comment back?

Comment: Comments are sometimes deleted when their constructive content has been incorporated into the post they apply to.   If you feel there was something in the Comment still of value, you might add a Comment to that author's attention asking to repost it.

Comment: I believe I identified the comment you enjoyed, and I've undeleted it. I would not necessarily say that it contributes much to the answer, but I agree that it's colorful.

Comment: @mixedmath yes that is the comment. I wouldn't say I *enjoyed* it, it is my own comment. Perhaps I should add it to the answer instead.

Comment: If you think a comment "contribute[s] greatly to the answer," it is good practice to integrate the content of the comment into the answer. This is especially true if it is your very own comment. Sometimes there may be reasons against this, but in the present case there is really no reason not to have that in the answer if you think it is relevant. You can format the post so that it is set off if you want to have it somewhat as an after thought.

Comment: The above was written before your latest comment. Yes, you should add this to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in text of the comment, you could try [Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6661/laplace-transformations-for-dummies), [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6661/laplace-transformations-for-dummies/) or check whether it still exists in [Data Explorer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info). (The data are only updated once a week.)

Both in Google Cache and the [last version archived in Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20161028125334/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6661/laplace-transformations-for-dummies) I only see these two comments:

> Poem in English = Differential Equation. Interpretation in English = Solution of Differential Equation. Translate to French = Take Laplace Transform. Poem in French (better interpreter) = Algebraic Equation (easier to solve). Interpretation in French = Laplace Transform of Solution of Differential Equation. Translate back into English = Inverse Laplace Transform
>
> +1 pour la métaphore!

I got exactly the same two comments using [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/646739/comments-on-a-given-post?postid=219688). (Which means that the comments were deleted after last update of data in the Data Explorer.)

---

If you want to get a deleted comments back, moderators can undelete comments deleted by mods (not comments deleted by the author) according to answer here: [Is undelete of comments already deleted.. possible?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25456/is-undelete-of-comments-already-deleted-possible) But you'll get probably more info on this from the mods.